# When we need to import component (parent/child) in another component (child/parent)?

Tags: angular

I am following the tutorial in angular official website (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3).

1. When I learn how parent component (**AppComponent**) communicate with child component(**HeroDetailComponent**), since we add this in the parent component's template, `<hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></hero-detail>`, it looks like to me that parent component talks with child component, why we do not import child component into parent component (`import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';`
   ) and import parent component into child component (`import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';`)?
2. If we do not do that, how can angular know how this works (`[hero]="selectedHero"`)?  **'hero'** is child component's property, **'selectedHero'** is parent component's property?
3. When should we need to import component? When we do not need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't quite understand why we need imports. Essentially, modules allow us to split code into different files. Suppose you have the following in one file/module:

```
class AComp {}

class BComp {
   constructor() {
       // creates new instance of AComp
       new AComp();
   }
}
```

Now, you can see here that BComp uses **reference** to the AComp class to create an instance of that class. Then we decide to split these classes into different modules/classes:

```
----------------------------- a-comp.js -----------------------------

class AComp {}

----------------------------- b-comp.js -----------------------------

class BComp {
   constructor() {
       // creates new instance of AComp
       new AComp();
   }
}
```

If you run `b-comp.js` now the JavaScript engine will throw an error because it will say that there's no `AComp` class in the `b-comp.js` file/module. So we need to tell JS engine where to look for `AComp`. And we do that by importing:

```
import { AComp } from 'a-comp';
class BComp {
   constructor() {
       // creates new instance of AComp
       new AComp();
   }
}
```

Now everything will work fine.

> When should we need to import component? When we do not need to?

As you can see we **had to use import because we use** `AComp` class reference in the `b-comp.js` file/module. If we didn't use `AComp` class reference in the `BComp` file/module, there would be no need to import `AComp` class.

> ...why we do not import child component into parent component

As you can see from the tutorial, neither `AppComponent` class uses `HeroDetailComponent` class reference directly in the file/module code, nor `HeroDetailComponent` uses `AppComponent` class reference. So there's no need to import them.

> If we do not do that, how can angular know how this works
>   ([hero]="selectedHero")? 'hero' is child component's property,
>   'selectedHero' is parent component's property?

Because that can be inferred from the information presented in the parent `AppComponent` template and Angular compiler uses this syntax `[hero]="selectedHero"` to get all the required information.